# C++ custom template with unordered_map

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a custom template, and have such code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    T *allocate(size_type n, const void *hint=0);

    T *allocate_at_least(size_type n);

    void deallocate(T *p, size_type n);
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Allocator<T>&, const Allocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    using T = long int;

    std::unordered_map<
        T,
        T,
        std::hash<T>,
        std::equal_to<T>,
        Allocator< std::pair<const T, T> >
    > a;
}
```

It works with vector, but it fails somewhere inside the templates when I use unordered_map.
Can you help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?
Here is the error:

`error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<Allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const long, long>, false>>>::__buckets_alloc_type' (aka 'Allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node_base *>')`

And link to code: https://godbolt.org/z/zje3EGjb6

P.S. If I replace `Allocator` to `std::allocator` everything works fine.

Comment: It's needs (3) and that stops the auto generation of (1) so you have to add that as well see  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator - live (struct name slightly changed for my readability) https://godbolt.org/z/ecq83sG1q

Comment: Thx to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to have a default constructor and a constructor that is like a copy constructor but parametrized on a non-T type. The following compiles.

```
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    T* allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    T* allocate_at_least(size_type n) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_type n) {
    }

    Allocator() {} // <= this

    template <class U>
    Allocator(const Allocator<U>&) {} // <= and this
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Allocator<T>&, const Allocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    using T = long int;

    std::unordered_map<
        T,
        T,
        std::hash<T>,
        std::equal_to<T>,
        Allocator< std::pair<const T, T> >
    > a;
}
```